# AssertionError: group argument must be None for now in a python library

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, gdelt

I'm trying to use a library called gdelt which simply downloads data from gdelt website or from Google Query i'm not sure. for installing and other info pls [visit](https://github.com/linwoodc3/gdeltPyR/tree/master) or

```bash
pip install gdeltPyR
```

You can also install directly from github

***bash***

```
pip install git+https://github.com/linwoodc3/gdeltPyR
```

it's been a long time that anyone has updated it and unfortunately i need it for my master thesis so it would be a huge help if i can fix it some how.

if we want to send a request for `events` or `mentions`  table it would work but unfortunately for gkg table it doesn't work.

if you send the request for only one day it works like a charm.

```
results = gd.Search('2016 10 19',table='gkg')
```

but when i set `coverage=True` or when i query for a time period, it returns this error  `AssertionError: group argument must be None for now`.

The Code that cuases the error:

`results = gd.Search(['2016 10 19','2023 01 22'],table='gkg')`

the whole error with Traceback:

```
File [c:\Users\\anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\gdelt\base.py:634](file:///C:/Users//anaconda3/envs/myenv/Lib/site-packages/gdelt/base.py:634), in gdelt.Search(self, date, table, coverage, translation, output, queryTime, normcols)
    630     downloaded_dfs = list(pool.imap_unordered(eventWork,
    631                                               self.download_list))
    632 else:
--> 634     pool = NoDaemonProcessPool(processes=cpu_count())
    635     downloaded_dfs = list(pool.imap_unordered(_mp_worker,
    636                                               self.download_list,
    637                                               ))
    638 pool.close()

File [c:\Users\\anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py:215](file:///C:/Users//anaconda3/envs/myenv/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py:215), in Pool.__init__(self, processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild, context)
    213 self._processes = processes
    214 try:
--> 215     self._repopulate_pool()
    216 except Exception:
    217     for p in self._pool:

File [c:\Users\\anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py:306](file:///C:/Users//anaconda3/envs/myenv/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py:306), in Pool._repopulate_pool(self)
    305 def _repopulate_pool(self):
--> 306     return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
    307                                         self._processes,
    308                                         self._pool, self._inqueue,
    309                                         self._outqueue, self._initializer,
    310                                         self._initargs,
    311                                         self._maxtasksperchild,
    312                                         self._wrap_exception)

File [c:\Users\\anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py:322](file:///C:/Users//anaconda3/envs/myenv/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py:322), in Pool._repopulate_pool_static(ctx, Process, processes, pool, inqueue, outqueue, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild, wrap_exception)
    318 """Bring the number of pool processes up to the specified number,
    319 for use after reaping workers which have exited.
    320 """
    321 for i in range(processes - len(pool)):
--> 322     w = Process(ctx, target=worker,
    323                 args=(inqueue, outqueue,
    324                       initializer,
    325                       initargs, maxtasksperchild,
    326                       wrap_exception))
    327     w.name = w.name.replace('Process', 'PoolWorker')
    328     w.daemon = True

File [c:\Users\\anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py:82](file:///C:/Users//anaconda3/envs/myenv/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py:82), in BaseProcess.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, daemon)
...
---> 82     assert group is None, 'group argument must be None for now'
     83     count = next(_process_counter)
     84     self._identity = _current_process._identity + (count,)

AssertionError: group argument must be None for now
```

this is part of the code in file ***base*** which error occours (the link to the [file just in case](https://github.com/linwoodc3/gdeltPyR/tree/master/gdelt)).

```
elif self.version == 2:

            if self.table == 'events' or self.table == '':
                columns = self.events_columns
                if self.coverage is True:  # pragma: no cover

                    self.download_list = (urlsv2events(v2RangerCoverage(
                        _dateRanger(self.date))))
                else:

                    self.download_list = (urlsv2events(v2RangerNoCoverage(
                        _dateRanger(self.date))))

            if self.table == 'gkg':
                columns = self.gkg_columns
                if self.coverage is True:  # pragma: no cover

                    self.download_list = (urlsv2gkg(v2RangerCoverage(
                        _dateRanger(self.date))))
                else:
                    self.download_list = (urlsv2gkg(v2RangerNoCoverage(
                        _dateRanger(self.date))))
                    # print ("2 gkg", urlsv2gkg(self.datesString))

            if self.table == 'mentions':
                columns = self.mentions_columns
                if self.coverage is True:  # pragma: no cover

                    self.download_list = (urlsv2mentions(v2RangerCoverage(
                        _dateRanger(self.date))))

                else:

                    self.download_list = (urlsv2mentions(v2RangerNoCoverage(
                        _dateRanger(self.date))))



if isinstance(self.datesString, str):
        if self.table == 'events':

            results = eventWork(self.download_list)
        else:
            # if self.table =='gkg':
            #     results = eventWork(self.download_list)
            #
            # else:
            results = _mp_worker(self.download_list, proxies=self.proxies)

    else:

        if self.table == 'events':

            pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
            downloaded_dfs = list(pool.imap_unordered(eventWork,
                                                      self.download_list))
        else:

            pool = NoDaemonProcessPool(processes=cpu_count())
            downloaded_dfs = list(pool.imap_unordered(_mp_worker,
                                                      self.download_list,
                                                      ))
        pool.close()
        pool.terminate()
        pool.join()
        # print(downloaded_dfs)
        results = pd.concat(downloaded_dfs)
        del downloaded_dfs
        results.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

i found partially the answer here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread

but i don't know how i can change and exactly what to change.
this is the first time that i probably need to change a library in order to be able to write my own code. any help would be appreciated.

### EDIT:

here's a [jupytur notebook](https://github.com/linwoodc3/gdeltPyR/blob/master/examples/Basic%20gdeltPyR%20Query.ipynb) in which you can easily test.

Comment: Problem is the simple assignment here: https://github.com/linwoodc3/gdeltPyR/blob/master/gdelt/base.py#L57 which must be written instead similar to https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L180 Currently I don't know exactly how this should be done in combination with handling the context (`ctx`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `base.py` file line `54` to `57`, patch them as follows.

```py
def dummy_process(self, ctx, *args, **kwargs):
    return NoDaemonProcess(*args, **kwargs)

# We sub-class multiprocessing.pool.Pool instead of multiprocessing.Pool
# because the latter is only a wrapper function, not a proper class.
class NoDaemonProcessPool(multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    Process = dummy_process
```

---

alteratively you can monkey-patch it yourself when importing the module.

```py
from gdelt.base import NoDaemonProcess, NoDaemonProcessPool

def dummy_process(self, ctx, *args, **kwargs):
    return NoDaemonProcess(*args, **kwargs)

NoDaemonProcessPool.Process = dummy_process
```

---

basically [multiprocessing.Pool.Process](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L180) is expected to be called as `Process(ctx, *args, **kwargs)`, while `NoDaemonProcessPool` is expecting to be constructed with `Process(**kwargs)`, so this wrapper just peels off the `ctx` ... and `self`, because it is no-longer a static method.

Comment: Can you include a note on what is being patched and how it fixes the problem?

Comment: when i use your monkey-patch then my code `results = gd.Search(['2016 10 19','2023 01 22'],table='gkg')` it still returns the same error, can you add my code as well so i exactly understand how it fixes the problem, tnx

Comment: @MostafaBouzari try again now.

Comment: if i replace the signature of process method in line **180** with `(ctx, *args, **kwargs)` then would fix the problem right? (p.s. tnx for the monkey-patch)

Comment: @MostafaBouzari no, the library `gdeltPyR` is overriding that method entirely, you can only modify `gdeltPyR`.